# Protractor - open browser, wait, run tests

Tags: protractor

I am learning Protractor and it seems great. But I'd like to run couple of specs on a single page opening. How can I achieve that? My problem is, a lot of stuff on my page is loaded via ajax, some by cascade.

Currently, I am running specs by using `wait` and `beforeEach`. Here's the code:

```
const br = browser;
const url = 'http://localhost:3000';

br.ignoreSynchronization = true;


describe('Component', () => {
    beforeEach(() => { br.get(url); });

    it ('should be present', () => {
        expect(element(by.className('news-list__wrapper')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
    });

    it ('should render children', () => {
        br.wait(() => {
            return element(by.className('news-block')).isPresent();
        }, 2500).then((r) => { if (r) { console.log('\n ✓ Component renders children') } });
    });

    it ('should render images', () => {
        br.wait(() => {
            return element.all(by.className('news-block__img')).first().isPresent();
        }, 2500).then((r) => { if (r) { console.log('\n ✓ Component renders images') } });
    });

    it ('should load images', () => {
        br.wait(() => {
            return element(by.className('news-block__image--loaded')).isPresent();
        }, 2500).then((r) => { if (r) { console.log('\n ✓ Component loads images') } });
    })
})
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `ExpectedConditions` in `browser.wait()`  for such ajax calls-
for more details on this you can refer the API doc - http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

```
 const br = browser;
 const url = 'http://localhost:3000';
 const EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

 br.ignoreSynchronization = true;


describe('Component', () => {
beforeEach(() => { br.get(url); });

it ('should be present', () => {
    expect(element(by.className('news-list__wrapper')).isPresent()).toBe(true);
});

it ('should render children', () => {
    br.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.className('news-block'))), 2500).then((r) => { if (r) { console.log('\n ✓ Component renders children') } });
});

it ('should render images', () => {
    br.wait(EC.presenceOf(element.all(by.className('news-block__img')).first()), 2500).then((r) => { if (r) { console.log('\n ✓ Component renders images') } });
});

it ('should load images', () => {
    br.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.className('news-block__image--loaded'))), 2500).then((r) => { if (r) { console.log('\n ✓ Component loads images') } });
})
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false` and use `browser.waitForAngular()` to make your scripts wait for all ajax call to get complete. The power of protractor is that it will wait for all asynchronous calls made by the page to be completed and then only it will execute the next line of code.